# Proving a general formula for the boost transformation of the electromagnetic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, special-relativity

> In inertial frame $\mathcal{O}$, a region of space-time is filled with constant electric field $\vec{E}$ and magnetic field $\vec{B}$. Another inertial frame $\mathcal{O}'$ has 3-velocity $\vec{V}$ relative to $\mathcal{O}$. What is the electromagnetic field $\left(\vec{E}', \vec{B}'\right)$ measured in $\mathcal{O}'$? Express the result in terms of $\vec{E}$, $\vec{B}$, $\vec{V}$, dot product ($\cdot$) and cross product ($\times$).

This is to get the general formula for the boost transformation of the electromagnetic fields. I know the general form of the Lorentz boost transformation. So, obviously the solution for this problem seems to be applying this boost transformation to the electromagnetic field tensor $F^{uv}$. That is, for the boost transformation $\Lambda^u_v$, calculate $F'^{ab}=\Lambda^a_u \Lambda^b_vF^{uv}$. But this seems like a tremendous amount of work... Is there any more efficient solution than this? Could anyone suggest me?

Comment: Look at how $A^a$ transforms.

Comment: Then I also must see how $\partial_a$ transforms. Right?

Comment: You're making life too hard for yourself. Forget calculus altogether at the start: just write $\phi',\,\mathbf{A}'$ in terms of their unprimed counterparts.

Comment: Use w.l.o.g.w.c.a.t. (without loss of generality, we can assume that). For example, assume that the velocity is in the $z$-direction, derive some formulae, then generalize back to dots and crosses based on the patterns. The answer is also in Jackson's electromagnetism textbook.

Comment: In my answer here  : [Is it a typo in David Tong's derivation of spin-orbit interaction?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/518040/is-it-a-typo-in-david-tongs-derivation-of-spin-orbit-interaction/518161#518161) for the configuration of two inertial systems as in Figure-01 the space-time Lorentz transformation is given by equations (03). The Lorentz transformation of the electromagnetic field is given by equations (04). I would  post in an answer the proof of this transformation of the electromagnetic field only if a moderator  untags the question as "homework-and-exercises".

Comment: My answer here: [Conceptual question about special relativity in electrodynamics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/555406/157014) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course.
There are three different methods at least

- using transformation of the electromagnetic field tensor $F^{\mu\nu}$ (which is TOO LONG!!!)
- using the transformation of 4-vector potential $\mathbf A^\mu$
- using the Lorentz force $\mathbf{F}=q \mathbf{E}+q \mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{B}$