# Is it a typo in David Tong's derivation of spin-orbit interaction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, special-relativity, atomic-physics, hydrogen

A few lines below [equation 7.8](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/aqm/aqm.pdf) D. Tong writes

> The final fact is the Lorentz transformation of the electric field: as electron moving with velocity $\vec{v}$ in an electric field E will experience a magnetic field $\vec{B}=\frac{\gamma}{c^2}(\vec{v}\times\vec{E})$.

The note says that it was derived in another note but I couldn't find this expression.

Is this coefficient $\gamma/c^{2}$ correct? Griffiths derives this to be $-1/c^2$ and I did not find anything wrong there. See Griffiths electrodynamics, third edition, equation 12.109.

Then I looked at [this book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=PlZKUT3veHUC&pg=PA477&lpg=PA477&dq=in%20order%20to%20physically%20understand%20the%20spin%20orbit%20interaction%20ghatak&source=bl&ots=1Okor6MuVr&sig=ACfU3U3yXj5IObtBJ25OPZZSe5Jq8xaI0A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj8gOrtx6DmAhXxzDgGHQNCCCsQ6AEwCnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=in%20order%20to%20physically%20understand%20the%20spin%20orbit%20interaction%20ghatak&f=false) which uses Griffiths' expression in Sec. 20.5, but uses $\vec{p}=m\vec{v}$ instead to $\vec{p}=\gamma m \vec{v}$ to derive the same result. Which one is correct and why?

Comment: The $\gamma$ factor should be there but its effect can often be neglected.

Comment: @Frobenius Did you compare Griffiths eqn. with Tong's? Where is the factor $\gamma$ in Griffiths?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

In above Figure-01 an inertial system $\:\mathrm S'\:$ is translated with respect to the inertial system $\:\mathrm S\:$ with constant velocity
\begin{align} 
\boldsymbol{\upsilon} & \boldsymbol{=}\left(\upsilon_{1},\upsilon_{2},\upsilon_{3}\right) 
\tag{02a}\label{02a}\\
\upsilon & \boldsymbol{=}\Vert \boldsymbol{\upsilon} \Vert  \boldsymbol{=} \sqrt{ \upsilon^2_{1}\boldsymbol{+}\upsilon^2_{2}\boldsymbol{+}\upsilon^2_{3}}\:\in \left(0,c\right)
\tag{02b}\label{02b}
\end{align}

The Lorentz transformation is
\begin{align}                  
    \mathbf{x}^{\boldsymbol{\prime}} & \boldsymbol{=}  \mathbf{x}\boldsymbol{+} \dfrac{\gamma^2}{c^2 \left(\gamma\boldsymbol{+}1\right)}\left(\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\boldsymbol{\cdot}  \mathbf{x}\right)\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\gamma\boldsymbol{\upsilon}}{c}c\,t
\tag{03a}\label{03a}\\
 c\,t^{\boldsymbol{\prime}} & \boldsymbol{=}   \gamma\left(c\,t\boldsymbol{-} \dfrac{\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\boldsymbol{\cdot} \mathbf{x}}{c}\right)
\tag{03b}\label{03b}\\
\gamma & \boldsymbol{=} \left(1\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\upsilon^2}{c^2}\right)^{\boldsymbol{-}\frac12}
\tag{03c}\label{03c} 
\end{align}

For the Lorentz transformation \eqref{03a}-\eqref{03b}, the vectors $\:\mathbf{E}\:$ and $\:\mathbf{B}\:$ of the electromagnetic field are transformed as follows
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{E}' & \boldsymbol{=}\gamma \mathbf{E}\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\gamma^2}{c^2 \left(\gamma\boldsymbol{+}1\right)}\left(\mathbf{E}\boldsymbol{\cdot}  \boldsymbol{\upsilon}\right)\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\,\boldsymbol{+}\,\gamma\left(\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{B}\right) 
\tag{04a}\label{04a}\\
\mathbf{B}' & \boldsymbol{=} \gamma \mathbf{B}\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\gamma^2}{c^2 \left(\gamma\boldsymbol{+}1\right)}\left(\mathbf{B}\boldsymbol{\cdot}  \boldsymbol{\upsilon}\right)\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\boldsymbol{-}\!\dfrac{\gamma}{c^2}\left(\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{E}\right)
\tag{04b}\label{04b} 
\end{align}
Now, if in system $\:\mathrm S\:$ we have $\:\mathbf{B}\boldsymbol{=0}$, then from \eqref{04a}-\eqref{04b}
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{E}' & \boldsymbol{=}\gamma \mathbf{E}\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\gamma^2}{c^2 \left(\gamma\boldsymbol{+}1\right)}\left(\mathbf{E}\boldsymbol{\cdot}  \boldsymbol{\upsilon}\right)\boldsymbol{\upsilon}
\tag{05a}\label{05a}\\
\mathbf{B}' & \boldsymbol{=} \boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\gamma}{c^2}\left(\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{E}\right)
\tag{05b}\label{05b} 
\end{align}
Equation \eqref{05b} corresponds to Tong's equation (it remains to explain the minus sign).

From equations \eqref{05a}-\eqref{05b} we have
\begin{align}
\mathbf{B}' & \boldsymbol{=} \boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\gamma}{c^2}\left(\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{E}\right)
  \boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{1}{c^2}\left(\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\boldsymbol{\times}\gamma\mathbf{E}\right) 
\nonumber\\
& \boldsymbol{=} \boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{1}{c^2}\Biggl(\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\boldsymbol{\times}\left[\gamma \mathbf{E}\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\gamma^2}{c^2 \left(\gamma\boldsymbol{+}1\right)}\left(\mathbf{E}\boldsymbol{\cdot}  \boldsymbol{\upsilon}\right)\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\right]\Biggr) \boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{1}{c^2}\left(\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{E}'\right)
\nonumber
\end{align}
that is
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{B}' \boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{1}{c^2}\left(\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{E}'\right)
\tag{06}\label{06} 
\end{equation}
Equation \eqref{06} corresponds to Griffiths' equation.

Based on equations \eqref{04a},\eqref{04b} we have proved that
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{B}\boldsymbol{=0}\quad\stackrel{\eqref{04a},\eqref{04b}}{\boldsymbol{=\!=\!=\!\Longrightarrow}}\quad \mathbf{B}' \boldsymbol{+}\dfrac{1}{c^2}\left(\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{E}'\right)\boldsymbol{=0}
\tag{06.1}\label{06.1} 
\end{equation}
But we can prove the validity of its inverse
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{B}' \boldsymbol{+}\dfrac{1}{c^2}\left(\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{E}'\right)\boldsymbol{=0}\quad\stackrel{\eqref{04a},\eqref{04b}}{\boldsymbol{=\!=\!=\!\Longrightarrow}}\quad \mathbf{B}\boldsymbol{=0}
\tag{06.2}\label{06.2} 
\end{equation}
So these conditions are equivalent
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\:\:\mathbf{B}\boldsymbol{=0}\quad\stackrel{\eqref{04a},\eqref{04b}}{\boldsymbol{\Longleftarrow\!=\!=\!\Longrightarrow}}\quad \mathbf{B}' \boldsymbol{+}\dfrac{1}{c^2}\left(\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{E}'\right)\boldsymbol{=0}\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{\tfrac{a}{b}}{\tfrac{a}{b}}}}
\tag{06.3}\label{06.3} 
\end{equation}
Equation \eqref{06.2} is valid because
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{B}' \boldsymbol{+}\dfrac{1}{c^2}\left(\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{E}'\right)\boldsymbol{=}\gamma^{\boldsymbol{-}1}\mathbf{B}_{\boldsymbol{\perp}} \boldsymbol{+}\mathbf{B}_{\boldsymbol{\parallel}}
\tag{06.4}\label{06.4} 
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{B}_{\boldsymbol{\parallel}},\mathbf{B}_{\boldsymbol{\perp}}$ the components of $\mathbf{B}$ parallel and normal to the velocity vector $\boldsymbol{\upsilon}$ respectively.

$\boldsymbol{=\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!=}$

$\textbf{ADDENDUM}$

If in system $\:\mathrm S\:$ we have $\:\mathbf{E}\boldsymbol{=0}$, then from \eqref{04a}-\eqref{04b}
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{E}' & \boldsymbol{=}\gamma\left(\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{B}\right) 
\tag{07a}\label{07a}\\
\mathbf{B}' & \boldsymbol{=} \gamma \mathbf{B}\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\gamma^2}{c^2 \left(\gamma\boldsymbol{+}1\right)}\left(\mathbf{B}\boldsymbol{\cdot}  \boldsymbol{\upsilon}\right)\boldsymbol{\upsilon}
\tag{07b}\label{07b} 
\end{align}
so that
\begin{align}
\mathbf{E}' & \boldsymbol{=} \gamma\left(\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{B}\right)\boldsymbol{=} \left(\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\boldsymbol{\times}\gamma\mathbf{B}\right)  
\nonumber\\
& \boldsymbol{=} \boldsymbol{\upsilon}\boldsymbol{\times}\left[\gamma \mathbf{B}\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{\gamma^2}{c^2 \left(\gamma\boldsymbol{+}1\right)}\left(\mathbf{B}\boldsymbol{\cdot}  \boldsymbol{\upsilon}\right)\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\right] \boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{B}'
\nonumber
\end{align}
that is
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{E}' \boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{B}'
\tag{08}\label{08} 
\end{equation}

Based on equations \eqref{04a},\eqref{04b} we have proved that
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{E}\boldsymbol{=0}\quad\stackrel{\eqref{04a},\eqref{04b}}{\boldsymbol{=\!=\!=\!\Longrightarrow}}\quad \mathbf{E}' \boldsymbol{-}\left(\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{B}'\right)\boldsymbol{=0}
\tag{08.1}\label{08.1} 
\end{equation}
But we can prove the validity of its inverse
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{E}' \boldsymbol{-}\left(\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{B}'\right)\boldsymbol{=0}\quad\stackrel{\eqref{04a},\eqref{04b}}{\boldsymbol{=\!=\!=\!\Longrightarrow}}\quad \mathbf{E}\boldsymbol{=0}
\tag{08.2}\label{08.2} 
\end{equation}
So these conditions are equivalent
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\:\:\mathbf{E}\boldsymbol{=0}\quad\stackrel{\eqref{04a},\eqref{04b}}{\boldsymbol{\Longleftarrow\!=\!=\!\Longrightarrow}}\quad \mathbf{E}' \boldsymbol{-}\left(\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{B}'\right)\boldsymbol{=0}\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{\tfrac{a}{b}}{\tfrac{a}{b}}}}
\tag{08.3}\label{08.3} 
\end{equation}
Equation \eqref{08.2} is valid because
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{E}' \boldsymbol{-}\left(\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{B}'\right)\boldsymbol{=}\gamma^{\boldsymbol{-}1}\mathbf{E}_{\boldsymbol{\perp}} \boldsymbol{+}\mathbf{E}_{\boldsymbol{\parallel}}
\tag{08.4}\label{08.4} 
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{E}_{\boldsymbol{\parallel}},\mathbf{E}_{\boldsymbol{\perp}}$ the components of $\mathbf{E}$ parallel and normal to the velocity vector $\boldsymbol{\upsilon}$ respectively.

$\boldsymbol{=\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!=}$

The duality transformation of the electromagnetic field is produced by the replacements
\begin{equation}
\begin{matrix}
\hphantom{c}\mathbf{E}&\boldsymbol{-\!-\!\!\!\longrightarrow}&\boldsymbol{-}c\mathbf{B}\\
c\mathbf{B}&\boldsymbol{-\!-\!\!\!\longrightarrow}&\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}c}\mathbf{E}
\end{matrix}
\tag{09}\label{09} 
\end{equation}
These replacements must be done in the primed system also
\begin{equation}
\begin{matrix}
\hphantom{c}\mathbf{E}'&\boldsymbol{-\!-\!\!\!\longrightarrow}&\boldsymbol{-}c\mathbf{B}'\\
c\mathbf{B}'&\boldsymbol{-\!-\!\!\!\longrightarrow}&\hphantom{\boldsymbol{-}c}\mathbf{E}'
\end{matrix}
\tag{09'}\label{09'} 
\end{equation}
In the aforementioned we met pairs of dual equations or expressions, that is under a duality transformation they are transformed one to the other :
\begin{equation}
\begin{matrix}
\eqref{04a}&\stackrel{\mathtt{duality}}{\boldsymbol{\longleftarrow\!\!\!-\!\!\!\longrightarrow}}&\eqref{04b}\\
\eqref{06}&\stackrel{\mathtt{duality}}{\boldsymbol{\longleftarrow\!\!\!-\!\!\!\longrightarrow}}&\eqref{08}\\
\eqref{06.3}&\stackrel{\mathtt{duality}}{\boldsymbol{\longleftarrow\!\!\!-\!\!\!\longrightarrow}}&\eqref{08.3}\\
\eqref{06.4}&\stackrel{\mathtt{duality}}{\boldsymbol{\longleftarrow\!\!\!-\!\!\!\longrightarrow}}&\eqref{08.4}
\end{matrix}
\tag{10}\label{10} 
\end{equation}

$\boldsymbol{=\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!=}$

Equations \eqref{06} and \eqref{08} are the following equations \eqref{12.109} and \eqref{12.110} respectively
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\:\:\overset{\boldsymbol{-\!\!\!\!\!-}}{\mathbf{B}} \boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}\dfrac{1}{c^2}\left(\mathbf{v}\boldsymbol{\times}\overset{\boldsymbol{-\!\!\!\!\!-}}{\mathbf{E}}\right)\boldsymbol{.}\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{\tfrac{a}{b}}{\tfrac{a}{b}}}}
\tag{12.109}\label{12.109}  
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\boxed{\:\:\overset{\boldsymbol{-\!\!\!\!\!-}}{\mathbf{E}} \boldsymbol{=}\mathbf{v}\boldsymbol{\times}\overset{\boldsymbol{-\!\!\!\!\!-}}{\mathbf{B}}\,\boldsymbol{.}\:\:\vphantom{\dfrac{\tfrac{a}{b}}{\tfrac{a}{b}}}}
\tag{12.110}\label{12.110} 
\end{equation}
as shown  in *''Introduction to Electrodynamics''* by David J.Griffiths, 3rd Edition 1999.

$\boldsymbol{=\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!=}$

Comment: @Dhruv Maroo : Many thanks for your attention. I apologize since I rejected your edit. I like the double line as I have it in my answer.

Comment: Can you possibly give me a hint where I find the proof of the two vector equations you gave to describe the generalized Lorentz boost transformation given in the figure? I think the equations should correspond to the Lorentz matrix given in this question [link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/564534/is-every-lorentz-transformation-a-pure-boost-plus-some-rotation), but I cannot verify that. Can I exclude a typo in your 2 equations? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Roland Salz : I joined Physics SE as **diracpaul** in June'15 and I quit the site in Sep'15 for personal reasons. I came back as **Frobenius** in Mar'16. Under my answers as former **diracpaul** now you could see the name **user82794**. My 2015 answer here [Two sets of coordinates each in frames  O  and  O′ - Lorentz transformation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/200844/two-sets-of-coordinates-each-in-frames-o-and-o-lorentz-transformation) gives the details for your question about the Lorentz transformation along an arbitrary direction.

Comment: @Roland Salz : Also my answer here [Deriving  Λij  components of the Lorentz transformation matrix](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/588841/deriving-lambdai-j-components-of-the-lorentz-transformation-matrix?rq=1) is identical to the previous one. I suspect what do you consider as typo. Looking at equations (21.1) to (21.6) you will find that there is no typo.

Comment: @Roland Salz : It's prerequisite to know about the $1+1-$Lorentz transformation along the $x−$axis. Sincerely, I didn't have any reference with the proof of this more general Lorentz transformation (called also "boost"). I have produced this many years ago by my own.

Comment: @Roland Salz : The general Lorentz Transformation is given without proof in "CLASSICAL ELECTRODYNAMICS" by J.D.Jackson, 3rd Edition , § 11.3, equation (11.19), page 525.

Comment: Thank you very much for your many hints. I'm familiar with the boost along the x-axis. I transformed your equations into a Lorentz matrix, with CAS, but something is not correct with it. It is not quite identical with the one (which seems to be correct) I mentioned in the link above. So actually, for a day or two I have been trying to find where the error is (of course it can be in my own calculations). Tomorrow morning I will look at your links and continue searching. Thanks a lot for your kind help.

Comment: Frobenius: Thanks to your detailed derivations I have resolved all my issues. One last question: what graphics software do you use for your figures? They look perfect.

Comment: @Roland Salz :  Welcome. It's GeoGebra free software.

Answer (score 0):

$\vec{p}=\gamma m\vec{v}$ is the technically correct equation, but for non-relativistic particles where $|\vec{v}|\ll c$, the [Lorentz factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_factor) becomes
\begin{equation}
\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}\approx 1,
\end{equation}
and so can be neglected.

For your reference, I had a quick look and I believe Eq. (6.45) of his EM notes is where this is derived.

Not sure about the negative sign in Griffiths though.