# Lorentz transformation of the Electromagnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

Consider an inertial system $\mathcal{O}$ and a Lorentz boosted system $\mathcal{O}'$, moving with a velocity $\vec{v}$ with respect to $\mathcal{O}$. Then we have expressions for the electromagnetic fields as follows:
$$\vec{B}=\gamma\vec{B'}+\frac{\vec{v}}{v^2}(\vec{v}\cdot\vec{B'})(1-\gamma)+\gamma\frac{\vec{v}}{c}\times\vec{E'}$$
$$\vec{E}=\gamma\vec{E'}+\frac{\vec{v}}{v^2}(\vec{v}\cdot\vec{E'})(1-\gamma)-\gamma\frac{\vec{v}}{c}\times\vec{B'}
$$
Now, I want to find the condition that $\vec{E'}$ and $\vec{B'}$ have to satisfy such that there exists a $\vec{v}$ such that $\vec{E}=0$. I reckoned that the third term $\vec{v}\times\vec{B'}$ is perpendicular to the second term $\vec{v}$, so those two cannot cancel each other. However, how can I formulate these conditions in terms of $\vec{E'}$ and $\vec{B'}$?

Comment: If you are intended to follow @Chiral Anomaly's instruction then take a look in the **ADDENDUM** of my answer there :[Is it a typo in David Tong's derivation of spin-orbit interaction?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/518040/is-it-a-typo-in-david-tongs-derivation-of-spin-orbit-interaction/518161#518161). Start with equation (08):
$$
\mathbf{E}\boldsymbol{=0}\quad\boldsymbol{\Longrightarrow}\quad\mathbf{E}' \boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{B}'
\tag{08}\label{08} 
$$

Comment: After finding from (08) the necessary conditions on $\mathbf{E}',\mathbf{B}'$ for the existence of velocities $\boldsymbol{\upsilon}$  you must try to prove the sufficiency, that is the validity of the inverse of equation (08) : 
$$
\mathbf{E}' \boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{B}'\quad\boldsymbol{\Longrightarrow}\quad\mathbf{E}\boldsymbol{=0}
\tag{08'}\label{08'} 
$$

Comment: To accomplish this start from my equations (04a),(04b) and prove that
$$
\mathbf{E}' \boldsymbol{-}\left(\boldsymbol{\upsilon}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{B}'\right)\boldsymbol{=}\gamma^{\boldsymbol{-}1}\mathbf{E}_{\boldsymbol{\perp}} \boldsymbol{+}\mathbf{E}_{\boldsymbol{\parallel}}
\tag{08''}\label{08''}
$$
where $\mathbf{E}_{\boldsymbol{\parallel}},\mathbf{E}_{\boldsymbol{\perp}}$ the components of $\mathbf{E}$ parallel and normal to the velocity vector $\boldsymbol{\upsilon}$ respectively.

Comment: Thank you, I thinkn I can figure it out from myself right now! I just needed the hint to seperate parallel and perpendicular part