# Is (net) force invariant in special relativity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, special-relativity, invariants

I am aware that acceleration is not invariant under lorenrz transformations, but I was sure that the first postulate of special relativity implied that newton’s second law in its original form,  F=dp/dt, where p is the relativistic momentum, was invariant. However, the following 2 questions imply otherwise:

[Relativistic electromagnetism and electromagnetic forces on 2 protons](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/307685/261792)

[Magnetic force between 2 moving charges](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/596730/261792)

It seems that the magnetic force between 2 moving charges depends on the frame of reference, and even goes to 0 in the relativistic limit. Doesn’t this violate the first postulate of special relativity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that Newton’s Second Law in the form

$$\mathbf F=\frac{d\mathbf p}{dt}$$

is relativistically *form*-invariant, meaning that in another inertial frame

$$\mathbf F’=\frac{d\mathbf p’}{dt’},$$

does *not* mean that force doesn’t transform under a Lorentz boost. It *does* transform, in the same way as the time derivative of relativistic momentum does. $\mathbf F’\ne\mathbf F$.

See [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0507099) for a discussion of the Lorentz transformation of a three-force $\mathbf F$.