# Magnetic field between two moving particles contradiction

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

Suppose we have two moving particles, both with velocity $v$ (relative to the observer) and a distance of $r$ apart (perpendicular to the velocity of both particles). The charges are $q_1$ and $q_2$. The magnetic field from charge $1$ at the position of charge $2$ is then $$B=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\frac{q_1v\times \hat{r}}{r^2}.$$

Moreover the force acting on charge $2$ by this magnetic field is $$F=q_2v\times B.$$

Since $v$, $\hat{r}$ and $B$ are all perpendicular we have that the magnitudes of $B$ and $F$ are
$$B=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\frac{q_1v}{r^2}$$ and $$F=q_2v\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\frac{q_1v}{r^2}=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\frac{q_1q_2v^2}{r^2}.$$

However if we view the situation from the perspective of one of the charges, they are both at rest, there will be no magnetic field and only an electric field. The electric field of charge $1$ is now $$E=\frac{1}{4\pi \varepsilon_0}\frac{q_1}{r^2}.$$ The force on particle $2$ must now be $$F=q_2E=\frac{1}{4\pi \varepsilon_0}\frac{q_1q_2}{r^2}.$$
These two forces on charge $2$ must be equal and so $$\frac{1}{4\pi \varepsilon_0}\frac{q_1q_2}{r^2}=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\frac{q_1q_2v^2}{r^2}$$ which implies $$v^2=\frac{1}{\varepsilon_0\mu_0}.$$ But this implies that $v=c$ since $$c^2=\frac{1}{\varepsilon_0\mu_0}.$$ Where is the fault in my reasoning? Do the distances, velocities or charges somehow change according to relativity? What would the correct equations then be?

Comment: The force in the first case is a sum of both electric and magnetic fields according to the observer.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/307685/relativistic-electromagnetism-and-electromagnetic-forces-on-2-protons) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/596730/magnetic-force-between-2-moving-charges) questions.

Comment: @Triatticus But in that case the electric force would be the same both in case 1 and 2, so the magnetic force would be 0.

Comment: You should use Lorentz covariant quantities.

Comment: It's simpler to start with two at-rest charges (as there is only an electric field), and then boost them (perpendicular to their separation), into a frame where $E'=\gamma E$ and $B'=-\gamma\beta E/c$.

Answer (score 0):

**I Didn't get that why you ignored the electrostatic force in the the observers frame** however, if you consider the electrostatic force then it would straight away cancel and the eqn becomes meaningless this is because you are considering two different frames into one,*force is not independent of frame in case of charges*

Comment: This is a comment. Not an answer.

Comment: answer makes a question stand no more, thats what my answer has done